# JavaScript for visualizing, manipulating, and exporting data points?

Tags: javascript, python

I have been using Tkinter and Pygame for a GUI to visualize data points.
With Tkinter, files are chosen from a list, and then a Pygame window is open where the data points are graphed.
Pygame is not meant for data visualization, and I would like to use an alternative.

I want to use JavaScript to visualize the data, but I don't know how I would bring the large amounts of point data from my files into a browser window, and then have the user be able to manipulate the data (moving, adding, or deleting points), and then saving that data back out.

What tools do I need to bring the data into JavaScript, generate graphics for graphing and some other basic shapes (text, lines, dots), and then export the data out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[plotly.js](https://plot.ly/javascript/getting-started/) is a great JS library that will allow you to visualize any data on the web with ease. You can check out the link and search for some tutorials on the internet, such as this one, but I don't think that is the problem.

**The issue is with getting the data from a file.**

When it comes to the web, you will need some sort of web server that can serve and receive files.

The web browser allows the user to input the file (this can be done with html tag `input`), then it sends a request containing the file data to your web server (this is where your JS code is), where you can then do whatever you like with the data and send a response back to be shown by the browser.

Although web server might be easy to get started in, with many different languages you can do it in (including JavaScript), I'm assuming it is not in your interest to build web servers as of yet.

If you insist on building this with JavaScript, you will have to find another method to get the data you want to plot, or actually build some kind of server that can handle these files you want the user to input. If this is really for you, here is a [starting tutorial](https://www.nodebeginner.org/) for building web server with Node.js (JavaScript), and here is [another one](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Server-side/Django/Introduction) for building web server with django (Python)

**But if you don't like this idea and don't mind going back to Python, you can use matplotlib.**

Python has a 3rd party module called [matplotlib](https://matplotlib.org/tutorials/introductory/pyplot.html#sphx-glr-tutorials-introductory-pyplot-py), which allows you to very easily plot points and graph them with many different customizations.

So, after you extract your points from your files, you can then remove whatever Pygame code you were using and instead very simply do:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

...  # extracting your points from the files

plt.plot(xpoints, ypoints)
plt.show()
```

**Where `xpoints` and `ypoints` are the points from the files**

This will create a line graph. You can customize this graph by passing in an optional third argument to the `plot` function, for e.g:

```
plt.plot(xpoints, ypoints, "x")
```

This will only plot the points instead of drawing a line. You can also change "x" to "ro", "bo", "r+" and so many more.

You can refer to the link above to take a look at the matplotlib documentation and choose whether you would like to try it out or really still stick to JS. However IMO I think you will have to find another way to get your data in that case as building web servers takes time and understanding, and may be very confusing at first :)

Comment: Did this help? Please give me feedback? I'm interested to know :)

Comment: Thanks Dennis! If I do go through with this, I think I'll go the node.js + plotly.js route. Thanks again :)